# Is it possible to build an android application with PhoneGap strictly inside Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, html, cordova

My company wants us to explore PhoneGap and needs an application deployed to Android, Windows Phone and Blackberry. They want to use one development environment(Visual Studio).

I believe I have read that it is possible to deploy an app to an Android device using PhoneGap : build from inside Visual Studio, but I would like confirmation.

Thank you

Comment: While this might seem like a good idea in theory, it is not. Doing this will net you three apps with mediocre to abysmal usability, since the user interface guidelines for the three platforms are vastly different.

What the world needs is definitely not more apps that ignore the UI design guidlines for their respective OS.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

No. In theory yes, but in practice no.

This is not a technical problem, but a social problem in your company. The decision makers have not experience of building mobile applications and try to apply their existing knowledge to an area they don't know and they fail. Unless they can understand their own limitations you are screwed.

It is possible to edit source code using any text editor. However, Visual Studio will not have any IDE goodies, like e.g. launching Android application from IDE available. Forcing Visual Studio upon developers would just hinder the development process.

Sorry about being employed in such mismanaged company.

Comment: They are simply trying to figure out what the best solution is. We dont know weither to start down the cross platform or native path yet.

Comment: Just to note this answer is from time when things were different and a lot of has changed it three years. I would delete this answer if I could.

Answer (score 6):

[Nomad](http://www.vsnomad.com/) is a Visual Studio extension that can build for both iOS and Android directly from within the IDE using a PhoneGap based cloud build service.

Comment: This can be combined with the [Ripple Emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=da&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) plugin for Chrome to debug/explore phone features

Comment: Thanks for the tip but is there a free alternative to this?

Comment: @likestoski See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29584292/203371) above (I realize you commented two years ago, but I thought I'd add an update :) )

Answer (score 2):

After developing the application in Visual Studio you should be able to take your HTML/JS files, upload them to the PhoneGap Build service (http://build.phonegap.com) and have it compile/generate Android and Blackberry application files for you.

Alternatively, if you don't mind using another IDE for the last step, you can always import your HTML/JS files created in VS into a new Android or Blackberry Phonegap project and compile.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am wondering however if I can use PhoneGap:build if my application is dependent on Plugins such as ZXing (QR code scanner plugin) for Android, since I have only got it to work with Eclipse with the inclusion of libraries.

Comment: Probably not. Plugins tend to be platform specific. That being said you could always try to create your own plugins, this is a quick guide for Windows Phone: [http://www.risingj.com/archives/92](http://www.risingj.com/archives/92)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create android phonegap appliation using visual studio.. for more information pleasee see the below link..

http://sourcefreeze.com/cross-platform/visual-studio-cordova-plugins-for-cross-platform-mobile-apps/

Answer (score 0):

You could use ["Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/explore/cordova-vs). As PhoneGap is built atop of Cordova and are almost the same (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23676071/203371) answer) this might be suitable for your needs?

An overview taken from the referenced website reads:

> "Build cross-platform mobile apps for iOS, Android, and Windows
>   devices using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova. With an
>   extension for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 or Visual Studio 2015
>   Preview, Visual Studio gives you the tools you need to get started
>   building your first app using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript based on
>   Apache Cordova."