# Using PhoneGap within Visual Studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build an app that uses PhoneGap. I want to be able to launch the app from Visual Studio 2012 and load it into Android. Does anyone know how to do this? A walkthrough or template would be AWESOME. Thank you,

Comment: Have a look at this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040473/is-it-possible-to-build-an-android-application-with-phonegap-strictly-inside-vis

Comment: Those comments seem outdated. How does MonoDroid launch an Android app in the Android emulator from Visual Studio? There should be a similar way to do this with PhoneGap/Cordova from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phonegap within visual studio using plugin.. for more information please visit the below link..

http://sourcefreeze.com/cross-platform/visual-studio-cordova-plugins-for-cross-platform-mobile-apps/