# What is the Difference between Apache Cordova and PhoneGap?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant

Hi I need to develop a simple application which is hybrid which runs in kitkat version of android. Since it is possible with PhoneGap 3.3 I have been trying to install it.

But I am really confused a lot with the installation procedure.

First I installed nodejs in my windows 7 32 bit system.

Then I ran the commands from the phonegap website. This is the link http://phonegap.com/install/
I was able to create a project.
But I am facing an error and not able to start the emulator.(I set the environmental variable. )

Then I have gone through couple of ohter websites where they said to run the following commands.

C:> npm install -g cordova

And if I run any further command beyond that it is asking me to install Apache ANT.

But many folks said me that both phonegap and cordova are same.

So I am a little confused since I have to ask my superiors for the download and installation of software in my office PC.

Please suggest me any website that gives me the procedure to work on these.

Comment: a bite late but here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174511/is-there-a-difference-between-phonegap-and-cordova-commands

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Phonegap and cordova uses almost the same repository,but they are not the same.Phonegap is build on top of cordova.

Cordova's releases a version first and phonegap usually follows.

The main difference between the both is that phonegap allows you to build your app online
https://build.phonegap.com/

Both have very different documentation

Here's a link to cordova http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

And link to phonegap http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

If you notice the links in the phonegap plugin in the documentary,you will notice phonegap uses cordova's plugin

Phonegap constantly plays catch up with cordova.I am a little biased towards cordova.I suggest you decide which is better for you

Comment: @ShinyJos can you please explain a little more why are you biased towards Cordova? For me also I felt I'd like to go with Cordova than with PhoneGap. But I can't directly understand why it is better!

Answer (score 5):

PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is the engine that powers Chrome or Safari.

For more details you can read these blogs

[PhoneGap, Cordova, and what’s in a name?](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)

And this question on stackoverflow

[Is there a difference between PhoneGap and Cordova commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174511/is-there-a-difference-between-phonegap-and-cordova-commands)