# Speech to text plug in PhoneGap not working

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

There is something I am missing with phonegap. When I try the below code, on my Iphone (trough PhoneGap desktop for mac), it just don't do anything....

Here is my code to try to use the STT plugin found here:

https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin

In the main config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.speech.speechrecognition" />
   <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.speech.speechrecognition">
  <param name="apiKey" value="5eae11XXXXXXXXX9048a4ce836d" />  
</plugin>
```

And in my code found from the example (so it should work...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/>


<textarea id="textarea" rows=10 cols=80></textarea>
  <button id="button" onclick="toggleStartStop()"></button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var recognizing;
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.continuous = true;
    reset();
    recognition.onend = reset;

    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
      for (var i = resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        if (event.results.final) {
          textarea.value += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        }
      }
    }

    function reset() {
      recognizing = false;
      button.innerHTML = "Click to Speak";
    }

    function toggleStartStop() {
      if (recognizing) {
        recognition.stop();
        reset();
      } else {
        recognition.start();
        recognizing = true;
        button.innerHTML = "Click to Stop";
      }
    }
  </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there something in the config I am doing wrong?

Side-question: It says in the github page:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin
```

But it is not working, so I typed:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin
```

what difference between "cordova" and "phonegap"?

Comment: API key should be `preference`, not `param`.  For Cordova read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669757/what-is-the-difference-between-apache-cordova-and-phonegap

Comment: Thanks but it des not worki either. Thanks for the link.